# SQL- Case and Left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, case

I have three tables vcircuits (containing circuit detail), ttcchcarges (containing circuit charges) 
and tpc( containing contract detail). 
I am trying to include the pccontract information along with the circuit detail. So I would know which circuits 
have contract attached and vice versa.

Comment: You can't use `CASE` to decide what tables to join on.

Comment: As mentioned by Abe, your query doesn't make sense.  Often, the best way to describe what you want is to provide sample data along with desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the DBMS you are using so I will orient this towards SQL Server.

You cannot do conditional joins or decide whether or not to select columns conditionally in SQL Server.

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to select records regardless of whether or not there is a corresponding record in the joined table and then handle the results from there.  Example:

```
SELECT date, vendor, place, COALESCE(circuit, 'no circuits...')
FROM vcircuit as vc
LEFT JOIN circuit as c
on vc.product_code_id = c.pc
```

Your current query is no where near a valid SQL Server query so it's hard to determine exactly what you are trying to do, but hopefully this will get you started on the right track.